# Filter on SQLAlchemy relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am using Pyramid + SQLAlchemy and have the following set up

```
from sqlalchemy import orm
from __init__ import user_table  
from device import Device

class User(object):
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'User: ' + self.username

orm.mapper(User, user_table, properties={
  'devices': orm.relation(Device, backref='owner')
})
```

How can I add a filter when I access `user.devices`? When I try `user.devices.filter(Device.platform==1).all()`, I get the following error:

```
'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use a [Query-Enabled Property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#building-query-enabled-properties):

```
class User(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'User: ' + self.username

    # property
    @property
    def devices_filtered(self):
        return object_session(self).query(Device).with_parent(self).filter(Device.platform==1).all()

    # or simply a method
    def devices_filtered(self, platform):
        return object_session(self).query(Device).with_parent(self).filter(Device.platform==platform).all()
```

or see the [Dynamic Relationship Loaders](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html?highlight=dynamic%20relationship%20loaders#dynamic-relationship-loaders):

```
orm.mapper(User, user_table, properties={
  'devices': orm.relation(Device, backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')
})

# ...
user = session.query(User).get(_some_user_id)
devices = user.devices.filter(Device.platform==platform).all()
```

*Just read the referenced documentation for the full explanation on the topics.*

Comment: `lazy='dynamic'` does it. Thanks!